# Gatsby server side rendering with getServerData() working locally but not on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering, netlify

I have an example site built with Gatsby 4.25.0, Node 14.20.1 and React 18.1.0 and served on Netlify. There are two pages- `/test.js` and a dynamic page `/dogs/[breed].js`. The test page fetches a list of dog breeds from an API and renders them in a list of links:

```
// test.js
          <ul>
            {dogBreeds.map((breed, idx) => (
              <li key={idx}>
                <Link to={`/dogs/${breed}`}>{breed}</Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
```

The `[breed].js` page uses `getServerData()` to fetch an image of the breed passed to it from params and display it on the page:

```
export async function getServerData(context) {
  const { breed } = context.params
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random`)
    const data = await res.json()

    console.log(`data from the getServerData function: ${data}`)

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Response failed`)
    }

    return {
      props: {
        breed,
        imageUrl: data.message,
      },
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      status: 200,
      headers: {},
      props: {},
    }
  }
}
```

Running locally, this all works fine. I can navigate to the dynamic route from the links and the images show up fine. On Netlify, hovering over the links in `test.js` causes 404 errors to show up in the console from "loader.js" and "prefetch.js":

[image: Gatsby 4 server side rendering not working on Netlify]

And clicking a dog breed link on `/test` leads me to a 404. We are using `gatsby-plugin-netlify` and `@netlify/plugin-gatsby`.